# Checkboxlist snapping to top in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, autopostback

I am using two checkboxlist. When an item from 1st is selected, the 2nd checkboxlist gets populated. I am using autopostback = true. However when I click an item from 1st checkboxlist, the list gets snapped back to top. I want to use autopostback = true, but the checkboxlist should not snap back to top.

```cs
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="issuers">
            <div>
                <label>Issuer:</label><br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIssuers" DataSource='<%# GetIssuers() %>'
                    runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIssuers_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Club:</label><br />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbAllClubs" Text="All Clubs" /><br />
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ddlClubs"
                    runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClubs_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Account Definitions:</label><br />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbAllAccountDefinitions" Text="All Account Definitions" /><br />
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblAccountDefinitions"
                    runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblAccountDefinitions_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="false"
                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried JQuery but couldn't quite figure out how to solve this problem

Comment: plz put your code here!

Comment: added the code plz chk out

Comment: Just use the `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` property and set it `true`!

Comment: Does the page show the browser spinner on post back, or does the update panel seem to work, and not show a update? Also, I would move ANY and ALL and EVERY data source(s) for the check box lists to code behind, and NOT use a markup datasource= expression, since then you cannot control WHEN those data sources run. Move that to the page load event, nested inside of a if !IsPostBack code stub, and thus checkbox list data sources will not re-trigger.

Comment: Update panel works. The page is not refreshed. However the first checkboxlist is refreshed every time user checks/unchecks an item. The problem is I want to maintain the scroll position to where it is even if the checkboxlist is refreshed.